# Selenium Python Am I selecting a drop down item the best way?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on my first-ever Selenium Python project and am baby stepping through it. I have an inconsistent issue and want to see if there's a better way to code it.

I need to select "Active" from a drop-down menu. I'm selecting the drop down input element and clicking on it. This will open a child element of the input with the list items in it. Here's where the problem lies...sometimes the drop down element stays open and I can select "Active" and everything works great. Sometimes, however, the drop down element opens and closes immediately before I can pick "Active". I'm currently trying to sleep for 3 seconds after clicking on the input element, hoping that will solve the issue. It seemed to for a little while, but now then it will revert back to closing immediately.

So is there a better way to open this drop down box and select active?

```
#select the status drop down box and click to open it, wait 3 seconds to make sure it loads
#and select the 'A'ctive list item and click to select it
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "input-w_112"))).click()
time.sleep(3)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "w_113"))).find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@combovalue="A"]').click()
```

[image]

Sometimes the list items box will stay open, sometimes it closes immediately.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this task with executing a JS script from Selenium WebDriver.

- Select the drop-down menu you need.
- Select an option by its index.

### Code

```py
JS_script = """
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
menu.selectedIndex = 0;
"""

driver.execute_script(JS_script)
```